# Is it possible in android that don't ask for permissions mentioned in Manifest.xml file, if code is not in use?

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I've mentioned the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

in my manifest.xml. But NFC code is no more in use and I commented the source code. Means NFC is no more in use for my app, but while installing the app, it's still shows in installing window.
So, is it possible in android that don't ask for permissions mentioned in Manifest.xml file, if code is not in use? Thanks

Comment: I do not see any reason to adding NFC permission into manifest if you are not using NFC in your applicaion. Only one way is to remove NFC permission from manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because the Android system has no idea which permissions your application requires before run-time. Picture the following scenario:

You are writing an application, not specifying NFC permission as you're not using it in your code, but you ARE using a framework that in 50% of the implementations do use NFC (device manufacturer specific framework).

The Android system has no way of telling if the NFC permission is required and thus it relies on your explicit instruction for permissions

As I'm sure you've noticed, an exception will be raised if the permission does not exist for the specified action

The only way to make sure the requirement is gone is to remove the permission from the manifest (and frankly, is it that much of a deal?)

Answer (score 0):

Besides commenting out the unnecessary codes, you have to remove the **permission** from your `manifest` as well.